# запуск консоли при запуске .jar файла (java)

Tags: java, cmd, jar

у меня есть класс, скажем, выводящий в консоль "hello world"(в идее), но при билде и запуске этого jar файла консоль не запускается, так вот, как добавить эту консоль?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ОС Вы прежде всего работаете в графическом интерфейсе, а не в консоли, поэтому открывать Вам её намеренно она не будет. Если будете запускать приложение на Линуксе без граф.окружения, то увидите результат.

Используйте команду:

```
java -jar путь/имя_файла.jar
```

в терминале/командной строке для того, чтобы увидеть "Hello World".

Другой вариант: создать окно и поместить на нем всё, что угодно. Та консоль, которую Вы видите в среде разработке, выводится средствами самой же среды разработки.